# Graph lookup column id filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am using graph and I can filter using the lookup column id. The field is set from a people picker. Just wondering how don I work out the column id value and it's corresponding value. I.e id is 18 that equals joe blogs